# Using MsDeploy to create web site or virtual directory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

We're trying to figure out how to automate our website deployment. We've picked an existing project, and started playing around.

First, I used the Publish wizard from with VS2012 to create a Web Deploy Package. We then tried deploying the package as a website, through the IIS Manager, and that succeeded without a problem. We thought we were nearly there.

What was next was to learn how to run this from the command-line, so we could script it. And that's caused us no end of headaches.

We've been playing around with msdeploy.exe, and with the .cmd file that the publish wizard created, and while both methods seem to install the package as a virtual directory just fine, neither will install the package as a root website.

Browsing around on the web, I've run across this:

[Web Deploy iisApp Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569054%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> In a sync operation, the iisApp provider copies content to a folder under the destination site that you designate and marks the destination folder as an application. The iisApp provider cannot create a site. The iisApp provider will not create applications under sites that do not exist.

And

> If you want to synchronize a Web site and its related configuration, use the appHostConfig provider.

At this point, we don't know beans about iisApp, or appHostConfig, or whatever.  We didn't create a package that used one or the other, VS2012 did. We haven't a clue, at this point, how to convince VS2012's web publish to create an appHostConfig package, and for that matter, I don't know if we want to.

Here's the thing - whether a given website is installed as a root application or as a virtual directory is not something the developers control - it's a decision made by the implementation team. Or testing team usually installs any given website both ways, to ensure that both work.

And since IIS seems to be able to manage to install this package as a root site, there must be a way to get msdeploy to do it.

But how?